# Closure of a set in the Uniform Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $C = \{(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^\omega ~|~ \lim x_n = 0 \}$. I am trying to show that this set is closed in the uniform topology, which is the topology generated by the metric $\rho (x,y) = \sup d(x_i,y_i)$, where $d(x_i,y_i) = \min \{|x_i-y_i|,1\}$, the standard bounded metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Here is a partial attempt:

Let $(x_n) \in \overline{C}-C$. Then $\lim x_n = \ell \neq 0$, and without loss of generality suppose $\ell > 0$. Since $x_n- \ell < x_n < x_n + \ell$ or $x_n \in (x_n - \ell, x_n + \ell)$ for every $n$, clearly the set $\prod (x_n - \ell, x_n + \ell)$ contains $(x_n)$. Moreover, if $(z_n) \in \prod (x_n - \ell, x_n + \ell)$, then $x_n- \ell < z_n < x_n + \ell$ and by the squeeze theorem $0 < \lim z_n < 2 \ell$. Now, *if* this is open in the uniform topology, then we have an open neighborhood of $(x_n)$ that doesn't intersect $C$, giving us the desired contradiction.

At this point, I mistakenly thought that this was a basis element of the product topology, and therefore open in the uniform topology This is obviously a fallacious inference, but it still could be open. My question is, is this in fact open in the uniform topology? If so, I could use some hints on how to show this. If not, I could still some some hints!

---

Note the definition of closure I am working with is as follows: the closure of $A$ is defined as the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$. I do have the following characterization though: $x \in \overline{A}$ if and only if every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$. I do not have any notion of closure in terms of convergent sequences.

Comment: Just to be clear, by $\mathbb R^\omega$ you mean the set of sequences of real numbers?

Comment: @Math1000 Essentially: $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ refers to the space of all convergent real sequences.

Comment: @user193319 No, all sequences, convergent or not are in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ in the uniform metric.

Comment: The more useful way to look at the closure: all $x$ such that all metric balls around $x$ intersect $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x= (x_n)_n \notin C$, this means by the negation of convergence ,that there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the set $\{n: |x_n| \ge \varepsilon \}$ is infinite. Can you find some radius $r > 0$ that all points in $B_\rho(x,r)$ are also non-convergent to $0$, so not in $C$? This shows that $x \notin \overline{C}$ then, so $C = \overline{C}$.

Comment: I could use some more help. I tried taking $r = \min \{1,\epsilon \}$, and then taking $(y_n) \in B(x,r)$ to be some sequence that converges to zero, I tried to derive some contradiction to show that $B(x,r)$ contains no sequences converging to zero, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: And if you half the radius?